# Proving a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How do you prove a set C is closed if around each point not in C, there exists a closed ball of non-zero radius which does not intersect C?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of a closed set?

Comment: What have you tried? What happens if you apply the definition of a closed set?

Comment: According to my notes, a set Is closed if its complement is open. The closure of a set consists of the points of the set as well as the accumulation points of the set. I dont understand this part: If I have to prove that the complement is open, why is it that in the question, I have to prove there exists a closed ball that does not intersect C? I am so confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show C complement is open. Then you'll have C is closed. 
You get openness of C complement by your assumption.

Comment: I do know that I have to prove the complement to be open in order to prove a set to be closed. However, I dont know how does that relate to closed balls around each point that is not in C?

Comment: If a set is open, then the complement is closed (and vice-versa). Here you're given that all points not in C have a closed (non-zero radius) ball around it. All points not in C are equal to C complement. We know a set is open if for all points, there exists an open ball around it, such that the open ball is contained in the set. We know there exists a closed ball for all points in C complement, and so take the interior of the closed ball to get an open ball with a non zero radius. This proves it's open.